# Displaying difference of only month year range duration using Jquery DatePicker IN n month n year format

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently I am building some application and I need to take the difference of the month and year range selected by user, but its not working for me.

I'm just getting the date selected by user, but not the difference. The **datepicker** method is giving the current system date.

What I want is

```
from date: Aug-2016
To date: Sep-2017
Difference: 1 month 1 year
```

AND

```
from date: Aug-2017
To date: Oct-2017
Difference: 2 month
```

Any suggestions

```js
$("#from, #to").datepicker({ 
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',            
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) { 
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();             
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  },
  beforeShow : function(input, inst) {
    if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
      year = datestr.substring(datestr.length-4, datestr.length);
      month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length-5),      $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));    
    }
    var other = this.id == "from" ? "#to" : "#from";
    var option = this.id == "from" ? "maxDate" : "minDate";        
    if ((selectedDate = $(other).val()).length > 0) {
      year = selectedDate.substring(selectedDate.length-4, selectedDate.length);
      month = jQuery.inArray(selectedDate.substring(0, selectedDate.length-5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
      $(this).datepicker( "option", option, new Date(year, month, 1));
    }
  }
});      
            
    
//button click function     
$("#btnShow").click(function(){ 
  if ($("#from").val().length == 0 || $("#to").val().length == 0){
    alert('All fields are required');
  } else {
    alert('Selected Month Range :'+ $("#from").val() + ' to ' + $("#to").val());
  }
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div style="text-align:center;">
  <label for="from">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="from" name="from" readonly="readonly" />
  <label for="to">to</label>
  <input type="text" id="to" name="to" readonly="readonly"  />
  <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: /I am getting the user entered "from" and "to" date here by using `($("#from").val() and ($("#to").val().But if using `$("#from").datepicker.`('getDate') or  $("#to").datepicker.('getDate'),I am` `getting the system date only.So I am unable to use getMonth(),getFullYear()` `methods also as they also return system month and year.Any suggestions highly appreciated`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please find below mentioned solution. Here you can find difference between range in months.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1)).trigger('change');
            }
        },
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            $("#to").datepicker("option", {minDate: new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1)})
        }
    });
    $('#from').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    $('#to').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1)).trigger('change');
        }
    });
    
    $("#btnShow").click(function() {
        if ($("#from").val().length == 0 || $("#to").val().length == 0) {
            alert('All fields are required');
        } else {
            var startDay = new Date($("#from").val());
            var endDay = new Date($("#to").val());
            var date2_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(endDay.getUTCFullYear(), endDay.getUTCMonth()));
            var date1_UTC = new Date(Date.UTC(startDay.getUTCFullYear(), startDay.getUTCMonth()));

            var months = date2_UTC.getMonth() - date1_UTC.getMonth();
            if (months < 0) {
                date2_UTC.setFullYear(date2_UTC.getFullYear() - 1);
                months += 12;
            }
            var years = date2_UTC.getFullYear() - date1_UTC.getFullYear();

            if (years > 0) {
                if(months > 0)
                  $('#result').html(years + " year " + " " + months + " month");
                else
                  $('#result').html(years + " year ");
                
            } else {
                $('#result').html(months + " month");
            }

        }
    });
});
```

```css
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style>.ui-datepicker-calendar {display: none;}</style>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <label for="from">From</label>
    <input type="text" id="from" name="from" readonly="readonly" />
    <label for="to">to</label>
    <input type="text" id="to" name="to" readonly="readonly"  />
    <input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Show" /> 
</div>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: gr8..bro .is it possible to take the field blank blank and let user to select date and if click on present then it will take the present date. Like u have set it to present date.Any suggestions